Equivalence of Two Latent Structures in Causal Inference
This is a claim made by Professor Judea Pearl in his classical monograph Causality: Models, Reasoning and Inference (footnote 5 in Section 2.3). For the two causal structures below (where "$(*)$" represents a hidden variable with any number of states), the author stated that

To verify that (a) and (b) are equivalent, we note that (b) can mimic (a) if we let the link $a \leftarrow *$ impose equality between the two variables. Conversely, (a) can mimic (b), since it is capable of generating every distribution that possesses the independencies entailed by (b).


I had a hard time to verify the "Conversely" direction of this argument. It seems to imply that the following equality holds for any r.v. $u$ (assuming all r.v.s in the graph are discrete):
\begin{align*}
p(a)p(b)p(c|a, b)p(d|c) = \sum_u p(u)p(b)p(a|u)p(c|u, b)p(d|c),
\end{align*}
or
\begin{align*}
p(c|a, b) = \sum_u p(u|a)p(c|u, b) \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align*}
However, $\eqref{1}$ is really difficult to prove (if my understanding was correct), or did I misunderstand the following definition of structure preference?

Definition 2.3.3 (Structure Preference) One latent structure $L = \langle D, O \rangle$ is preferred to another $L' = \langle D', O\rangle$ (written $L \preceq L')$ if and only if $D'$ can mimic $D$ over $O$ -- that is, if and only if for every $\Theta_D$ there exists a $\Theta_{D'}'$ such that $P_{[O]}(\langle D', \Theta_{D'}'\rangle) = P_{[O]}(\langle D, \Theta_{D}\rangle)$. Two latent structures are equivalent, written $L \equiv L'$, if and only if $L \preceq L'$ and $L \succeq L'$.



it is capable of generating every distribution that possesses the independencies entailed by (b) I guess it can be explained by the theory of d-separation. By the way, there may be something wrong in your equation: you forgot to multiply p(b) in the right side of the first line.


It turns out I do have some quite fatal misunderstanding on Definition 2.3.3. In fact, the goal is not to "prove" $(1)$ in the question. Instead, what we need is to demonstrate that there always exist some probability distributions $\tilde{p}$ (i.e., the $\Theta_{D'}'$ in Definition 2.3.3) such that with the given distributions $p(u), p(b), p(a|u), p(c|u, b)$ and $p(d|c)$ (i.e., the $\Theta_D$ in Definition 2.3.3) associated with graph (b), it follows that
\begin{align*}
\tilde{p}(a)\tilde{p}(b)\tilde{p}(c|a, b)\tilde{p}(d|c) = \sum_u p(u)p(b)p(a|u)p(c|u, b)p(d|c).
\end{align*}
This can be accomplished by setting (note that once we know $p(u)$ and $p(a|u)$, then $p(a)$ can be evaluated as $p(a) = \sum_u p(a|u)p(u)$, and $p(u|a) = p(a|u)p(u)/p(a)$, therefore every distribution appeared on the right side below can be read off from known distributions associated with graph (b)):
\begin{align*}
& \tilde{p}(a) = p(a), \\
& \tilde{p}(b) = p(b), \\
& \tilde{p}(d|c) = p(d|c), \\
& \tilde{p}(c|a, b) = \sum_u p(u|a)p(c|u, b),
\end{align*}
which is a mathematical way of interpreting Professor Pearl's statement "it is capable of generating every distribution that possesses the independencies entailed by (b)".
I want to thank Yuxuan's comment for pointing out a typo in $(1)$ of my original post. Without his help, it is hard to renew my thoughts and appreciate Definition 2.3.3 in the correct way.
